# Unique eigenvectors of the EM energy-momentum tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, classical-field-theory

This is a two-part question:
1) I understand that every tensor in a Minkowski 4-space has four eigenvectors, of which only one is timelike.  Under what circumstances, if any, does an EM energy-momentum tensor have four *unique* unit eigenvectors?
2) Is there a formula for the eigenvectors of the EM energy-momentum tensor in terms of $A^\mu$, $F^{\mu\nu}$ or $\vec E$  and  $\vec B$?

Comment: *I understand that every tensor in a Minkowski 4-space has four eigenvectors, of which only one is timelike.* I don't think this is true. For example, you could pick a basis consisting of 2 null vectors and two spacelike vectors. Then a matrix that was diagonal in this basis would have no timelike eigenvectors (assuming distinct eigenvalues).

Comment: Conditions for unique eigenvectors correspond to unique solutions to the quartic characteristic equation (unique eigenvalues $\leftrightarrow$ unique eigenvectors). I don't think the latter would give a nice physical interpretation nor expression, albeit an interesting mathematical problem.

Comment: A helpful example is a plane wave, described in orthogonal coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$, where the wave propagates along x and has E along the y axis and B along z. Then up to a constant, the energy-momentum tensor looks like 1,1,1,1 in the upper-left 2x2 block, and 0 everywhere else. There are two null eigenvectors and no timelike ones. This means that there is no frame in which the wave acts like a perfect fluid. (To get a perfect fluid made out of EM waves, you probably want some kind of incoherent state.)

Comment: That is helpful, but I'm mostly curious about the static or quasistatic cases, where E and B are not generally perpendicular and equal.

Comment: I've been searching for references that discuss timelike eigenvectors of stress-energy tensors, and it seems that most of them are focused either on general relativity or fluid dynamics.  They typically refer to *the* timelike eigenvector; and some refer to assigning a velocity based on "the" timelike eigenvector of a stress-energy tensor.  Also, the eigenvectors are orthogonal.  I get the impression that the example of a plane wave is exceptional because it allows two  eigenvectors to lie *on* the light cone.