# Under what conditions is field momentum an eigenvector of the stress-energy tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

This question is vaguely related to an [earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/479050/), but is more focused.

In a paper, [Electromagnetic Mass, Charge, and Spin](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236260413_Electromagnetic_Mass_Charge_and_Spin), *which apparently is not peer-reviewed*, the author relates a "matter field" to a spinor representation of the electromagnetic field.  The author states that field momentum of the "matter field" is an eigenvector of a field stress-energy tensor:

> We also demonstrate that condition (3) is equivalent to the requirement that momentum density of the matter field  is an eigenvector of the stress-energy tensor of the electromagnetic field. [page 4]

Unfortunately I haven't learned how to work with spinors yet, so am not able to check or understand the author's math.

A) In general, under what conditions would field momentum - or a component thereof - be an eigenvector of the stress-energy tensor?
B) Why should (or should not) this paper be taken seriously?

Comment: I personally would not spend any time whatsoever on this paper because (1) the author is an “independent researcher” with no academic affiliations, and I can’t find him in Google Scholar; (2) ResearchGate has no quality standards as far as I know; the paper was likely rejected by arXiv; (3) the paper is 6 years old and has gotten only two self-citations according to ResearchGate.

Comment: That was my inclination too.  However, it seems only fair that the work should speak for itself.  Wish I understood spinors.

Comment: Of A) and B), the former is my main interest:  under what conditions would field momentum - or a component thereof - be an eigenvector of the stress-energy tensor?